# Why protractor deprecated in jhipster?

Tags: protractor, jhipster

I am curious to understand why jhipster 7.8.1 deprecated the protractor. Is there roadmap to include any other end-to-end testing framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it was very flakey in CI tests. We found that Cypress is much more reliable, so that's the default now.